# Property injection without using attribute [Inject] with Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a controller and a customized ActionInvoker. I can set the customized ActionInvoker as following,

```
public HomeController()
{
    this.ActionInvoker = new MyActionInvoker(..);
}
```

But don't want to do this in every controller (and I don't want to use a base controller either). I want to use Ninject to inject the ActionInvoker. Since ActionInvoker is part of the base controller I can't add [inject] to it. I searched a lot and tried something like

```
Bind<HomeController>().ToSelf().WithPropertyValue("ActionInvoker", 
   x =>x.Kernel.GetService(typeof(IActionInvoker)));
```

But it didn't work. Am I doing it wrong? Or any suggestion to achieve what I wanted. Thanks

**Update:** This works, something else was wrong. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Which MVC version do you use and do you use any of the Ninject.Web.Mvc extensions? There are probably some side effects with your current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
Bind<IActionInvoker>()
    .To<MyActionInvoker>()
    .Using<SingletonBehavior>();


Bind<HomeController>()
    .ToSelf()
    .InjectPropertiesWhere(p => p.Name == "ActionInvoker");
```

Comment: Thanks. But the methods you mentioned were gone in ninject2. Anyway, the method I used works. It was something else wrong. It happens. :)